# How to make pictures in Bioblender

Tags: objects

I have downloaded Bioblender V0.6 and the pdb file of [this](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1ad4) molecule. The molecule contains two chains 'A' and 'B'.

If I check the "hydrogen" check box and import the pdb I get the following image:
[image]

However, I cannot see the hydrogens of this molecule. I would like that my molecule looks more like the picture that one can find on the homepage from Bioblender (see picture below). How can I achieve this?
[image]

As I already mentioned, my molecule contains two chains 'A' and 'B'. I would like to visualize my molecule such that one can identify each chain, as for example in the following picture (found in this [article](http://www.bioblender.eu/Database/blender_zoppe_et_al3.pdf)). How can I achieve this? 
[image]

**Edit:** Mike Pan noted that I do not have hydrogens in my molecule. Therefore I tried [this](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/ligand/ligandsummary.do?hetId=LNK) molecule with hydrogens in the pdb file. When I add it with Bioblender and check hydrogen, the molecule is represented in a very different style then the molecule from the Bioblender homepage - why is that?
[image]
I also tried to check Spacefill and I got the following result.
[image]
However, the hydrogen looks far bigger then in the Bioblender image (second from top). I do not know how I can scale all hydrogens. In the outliner, they are not grouped.

Comment: I'm not sure this quite belongs here, I left this in the queue because I hoped you could get an answer which you did. As it stands however, it's a rather localized issue as per the scope of this site seeing as you are using a special build of Blender. We are still in beta and aren't sure of what exactly to fit into our scope yet, will post a link to the relevant meta post discussing this soon.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the PDB file of [1AD4](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/1AD4.pdb) here, it looks like the PDB does not contain hydrogen. So you wouldn't see any Hydrogen atoms in the render.

As for colouring different chains, you can import each chain by itself, and then use a surfacing algorithm (MLP or EP) to generate a surface, once you have the surface, it should be easy to apply the material yourself.

If you want to create something simple without fiddling with Blender as much, take a look at [MolecularFlipbook.](https://www.molecularflipbook.org)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the new tool that looks very promising. I have edited my question with a molecule which contains hydrogen, but I was still not able to reproduce the image from Bioblender. Do you know if I do something wrong?